# Why spin 2 is related with attractive force?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, quantum-spin, interactions, carrier-particles

Excerpt from Introduction to Black hole physics, Valeri P. Frolov and Andrei Zelnikov.

In this textbook, there is comment about spin of gravitons as follows:

> For gravitating bodies the gravitational charge i.e. their masses,
>   always have the same sign and they attract each other. This property
>   is directly connected with the fact that gravitons have spin 2, while
>   the photons have spin 1.

Can anybody explain to me the reason, why spin 2 is related with attractive force in more detail?